# Remove modal from page in Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to remove the modal that has been added to the nav stack from the previous page. For example, I `nav.push` user to a page then from that page the user opens a modal. I have a `Observable.timer` inside the page and it triggers a `nav.push` when countdown reaches 0, so when this happens I want to close all modals opened when it is triggered? How do I close a modal opened from a specific page?

```
this.navCtrl.push(EndPage).then(() => {
  const indexModal = this.viewCtrl.index;
  this.navCtrl.remove(indexModal + 1);
  this.navCtrl.remove(indexModal );
});
```

**Modal closed after Observable.timer ends**

```
  answerModal : any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.countDown = Observable.timer(0, this.tick)
      .take(this.counter)
      .map(() => --this.counter).finally(() => this.endTimer());
      //this.countDown.subscribe(() => { }); 
  }

  endTimer()
  {
       this.answerModal.dismiss();
  }

  // user clicks to create modal
  newmodal() { 
    this.answerModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalanswersPage);
    this.answerModal.present();
    this.answerModal.onDidDismiss(data=>{ 
        console.log("closed"); 
    });
  }
```

Comment: not really clear what you are attempting.. you are opening a modal elsewhere and then pushing a page?

Comment: I am opening a modal from a page, pretty straight forward modal.present(). I want to close this modal from the page that called it

Comment: modal.dismiss()...

Comment: That only works if you call from inside the modal page, not from page that called the modal

Comment: actually you can call dismiss on the modal objct you create in parent page

Comment: I tried and gives error: ..'UnsubscriptionError: can not read property dismiss of undefined'. I added modal : any; before config and call this.modal.dismiss()

Comment: can you add the relevant code.. where you create the modal and where you are dismissing it?

Comment: Updating question with code

Comment: since you are adding timer in ngOninit it may be that modal dismiss is called before creation, have an if condition in `endTimer` .        `this.answerModal && this.answerModal.dismiss();`

Comment: Thanks I changed the ngOninit  to a normal function and it fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest put the counter inside the modal. The model has to be responsible to close the modal usgin the ViewController component. In that way you have to open the modal in your main page as you are doing right now.

```
  // user clicks to create modal
  newmodal() { 
    this.answerModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalanswersPage);
    this.answerModal.present();
    this.answerModal.onDidDismiss(data=>{ 
        console.log("closed"); 
    });
  }
```

And then your modal needs to implement the timer and dismiss.

**YourModal.ts**

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public viewCtrl: ViewController) {}      

  ngOnInit() {
     this.countDown = Observable.timer(0, this.tick)
          .take(this.counter)
          .map(() => --this.counter).finally(() => this.endTimer());
          //this.countDown.subscribe(() => { }); 
  }

  endTimer()
  {
       if(this.countDown)
           this.countDown.unsubscribe();
       this.viewCtrl.dismiss(false);
  }
```

You can see in the code above that I'm calling the dismiss method from the `ViewController` component. Because you are moving the timer inside the modal don't forget to unsubscribe your observables.

Hope it helps. If you are in doubts don't hesitate to let me know.